# how to dynamically identify duplicate records in hundreds of tables

Tags: sql, duplicates, procedure

I have spent so long trying to solve my problem to absolutely no avail.  I need to create a procedure or loop through whatever you want to call it that scans all tables in all databases in my warehouse and identifies duplicate records.  Clearly I want to avoid writing hundreds of queries and manually entering each column name from each table so it needs to be done dynamically.  I have 12 or so databases but hundreds of tables and perhaps thousands of columns.

how does one do this?

Comment: What constitutes a "duplicate"? What does your data structure look like? Which SQL product are you using? (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: SQL Server.  A duplicate would be an entire record so if an entry has 10 columns all 10 values would have to be the same as another record.  In other words, you'd concatenate all the values for a record (logic wise) and then compare that to all other records.

Comment: So you're looking for duplicates in any given table, not across tables?

Comment: well i guess both within and across

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started. You can write a cursor to go through the tables in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` then set the variables from there. Once you run this in a database you'll then need to copy and paste the code that gets generated and run that code to see duplicates.

```
DECLARE
    @column_list NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @table_name SYSNAME,
    @table_schema SYSNAME

SELECT @table_schema = 'MySchema', @table_name = 'MyTable'

SELECT @column_list = ''

SELECT @column_list = @column_list + '[' + C.COLUMN_NAME + '], '
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @table_schema

SELECT @column_list = SUBSTRING(@column_list, 1, LEN(@column_list) - 1)

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @table_schema + ''' AS TABLE_SCHEMA, ''' + @table_name + ''' AS TABLE_NAME, ' + @column_list + ' FROM [' + @table_schema + '].[' + @table_name + '] GROUP BY ' + @column_list + ' HAVING COUNT(*) > 1'

SELECT @sql
```